# Color of header is being changed when disable sorting header in tablesorter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tablesorter

```
    <table verticalAlign="${'center'}" tableType="${'bordered'}"
                        tableStripes="${'horizontal'}" id="searchResultsTable"
                        cssClass="tablesorter">
                        <thead>
                            <## Heading ##tableRow>
                                <a:tableColumnHeading id="sort">F</a:tableColumnHeading>
                                <a:tableColumnHeading>Id</a:tableColumnHeading>
                                <a:tableColumnHeading id="sortOnb">certificate</a:tableColumnHeading>
                                <a:tableColumnHeading>Issue Date</a:tableColumnHeading>
                                <a:tableColumnHeading id="sortOnc">Expiry Date</a:tableColumnHeading>
                                <a:tableColumnHeading id="sortOnd">Owner Group</a:tableColumnHeading>
                                <a:tableColumnHeading>Can</a:tableColumnHeading>
                                <a:tableColumnHeading>Algo</a:tableColumnHeading>
                                <a:tableColumnHeading>Size</a:tableColumnHeading>
                            </a:tableRow>
                        </thead>
```

jquery to disable sorting in $.ready func

```
    $("#searchResultsTable").tablesorter({
    {
    header:
    1 : { sorter : false },
    3 : { sorter : false}
    .
    .
    .

    }
    });
```

table sorter css

```
table.tablesorter thead tr th, table.tablesorter tfoot tr th {
    background-color: #e6EEEE;
}
table.tablesorter thead tr .header {
    background-image: url(tableSorterImages/bg.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center right;
    cursor: pointer;
}
table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortUp {
    background-image: url(tableSorterImages/asc.gif);
}
table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortDown {
    background-image: url(tableSorterImages/desc.gif);
}
```

i want to disable those header which dont't have id , i tried above jquery but it changes the color of header . Is there any way to disable them without having change in color.

i have tried this also , Suppose id="id" for 2nd column

```
$("#id").data("sorter", false);
```

Comment: It changes color of header to what? background-color: #e6EEEE; is for all enabled/disabled columns...

Comment: color of disabled columns was changed  to some color other than #e6EEEE . No visible effect in enabled columns

Comment: Please add an example in JSFiddle... What color was changed to (you can inspect element to see what css rules affect on element)?

Comment: not using simple html and there are many other thing.. So cant use js fiddle!! :(

Comment: Sorter is disabled on 1,3... (it should work this way) column so these columns are not affected by table.tablesorter thead tr .header, table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortUp or table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortDown (just table.tablesorter thead tr th) because they don't have class .header or headerSortUp or headerSortDown (because they are not sortable)... So probably some other css rule affect on your 1,3,.. <th>. Check css rules with inspect element on browser to see where is background-color changed. I understand that sorting disablement is working otherwise, right?

Comment: i tried changing color of non-sortable column using style parameter in html but i was unable to do so